# How do I use File.new to find a file from Rails?

Tags: ruby, file, paperclip

I am trying to read a file that has been saved on the /system folder using Paperclip, for example.  But when I use that .url method from Paperclip to read that file using File.new, I get that the file isn't found.  The directory is correct, but I still can't access it.

What is the right way to find a file for File.new for example?  I tried to point to other files, as well, and to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the [path method](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/b9d9fc449b12ba7c2a165c530fa80d787b3220b3/Paperclip/Attachment.html#path-instance_method).  That returns the filesystem path.